# In semiconductor physics, in context of PN junctions/pixel detectors, what is the difference/meaning of N-in-N and N-in-P technology?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

In semiconductor physics, in context of PN junctions/pixel detectors, what is the difference/meaning of N-in-N and N-in-P technology ? How could we have a N-N diode ?

Comment: Could you provide a link to such a description? That might clarify what you are asking.

Comment: thank you. You may consider for example :                                                                   https://cds.cern.ch/record/2285585/files/ATLAS-TDR-030.pdf   On page labelled 132 : "The n-in-p technology has been chosen because it is a single sideprocess, simplifying the product flow with respect to the n-in-n technology..."

Comment: After (finally) looking at the document, I think they mean n-i-p for both. Now, normally, this is often put as pin or p-i-n . The "i" stands for intrinsic silicon. What that means is you get a much thicker region where you can collect charges.

Comment: thank you for your kind explanation Jon.